# Do electrons and atoms/molecules have resonance frequency?

Tags: atomic-physics, frequency, molecules, absorption

I think most materials/objects, when you apply to them oscillating forces, they oscillate with specific intensity, according to the forces magnitude and frequency. But there is a specific combination of frequency that you make the material/object go crazy, i.e. oscillate with maximum intensity, which is the resonance frequency. I was thinking, do electrons of specific materials have such resonance frequency? Do solid or gas atoms/molecules have such resonance frequencies? Thanks!

Comment: In English this is called "resonance"

Comment: See de-Broglie wavelength for individual particles, and bond oscillation for molecules.

Answer (score 2):

They have multiple resonance frequencies. Taking molecules for certainty, we can have:

- resonances associated with the molecule rotation about different axes
- resonances associated with molecule bending
- resonances due to the electronic excitations (this is also true for atoms)
- resonances due to the [excitations within nuclei of the atoms](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565916/247642)

Depending on the type of molecule, some of these may be present to absent in the absorption/emission spectrum (depending on whether they couple or not to the EM radiation). The frequency increases from the top of the list to the bottom - rotational and vibrational resonances are often in radio or microwave range, electronic transitions in infrared and optical range, nuclear resonances in gamma range.

Answer (score -2):

Liquid water (H2O) resonance frequency is 13.56MHz.