# How nucleons get excited?

Tags: energy, electromagnetic-radiation, photons, nuclear-physics, radioactivity

Gamma rays can be released when nucleons at higher energy states fall down to lower energy states, but how do nucleons get that much high energy to release gamma rays?

Comment: "If a proton or a neutron inside of the nucleus jumps up to an excited state - generally following an alpha or beta decay - the new daughter nucleus must somehow release energy to allow the proton or neutron to relax back down to ground state." See [here](https://energyeducation.ca/encyclopedia/Gamma_decay).

Comment: The structure of the nucleaus is comparable to that of an atom's electron cloud Including a 'shell like' structure. Nucleons can thus be excited and can then relax like electrons.

Comment: Related: [Do nuclei emit photons?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/565913/247642)