# How exactly does one reaction of nuclear fussion exactly produce EMR of different types?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation, sun, photon-emission

Electromagnetic radiation from sun is more likely produced by the nuclear fusion, and at a go radiation is released but how is it possible for different types of radiation to be produced such as, gamma, x-rays, UV, visible light, infrared, microwaves, and radio waves?

Please answer, and let me know, if my question makes sense or if I have any mistakes. In the answer please try to use least possible math, I'm just a high school student.

Answer (score 1):

Nuclear fusion is the main source of solar energy, but no the only source of how this energy is converted into radiation. Thus,

- gamma rays are mainly emitted as a result of nuclear reactions
- ultraviolet, infrared, and optical waves are mainly result of relaxation processes within atoms
- X-rays are result of [Bremsstrahlung](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bremsstrahlung), i.e., acceleration or deceleration of charged particles
- radiowaves are a result of "slow" oscillations of masses of charge

In fact, there is a lot of overlap between these process - e.g., nuclear reactions can also emit radio wave radiation (e.g., [see here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/565916/247642)) - I indicated just the dominant outcome.

Comment: Which kind of EM radiation do we get when the positrons released in e.g. diproton decay annihilate solar electrons?

Comment: @J.G. I don't see how this is related to what I say... except, if you want to say that my list is not exhaustive - which I readily grant you.

Comment: I'm curious whether, for example, you folded such photons into "as a result of nuclear reactions", in which case they're gamma rays. At any rate, they're a major sources of solar photons; for example, both the p-p and CNO chains make more photons that way than through the formation of specific nuclei.

Comment: @J.G. The point I am making is that there are many different sources of solar radiation... I think it is more plausible than claiming that all of it comes from nuclear reactions. If you have data on how much different sources of radiation contribute, it could be interesting.